# Past particle vs being past participle in passive sentence

Tags: past-participles

What is the part of of speech of "done" in the sentence below. I think it was "are being done" but we've just contracted it. I want to know why and how I can make such sentences.

> "Robots will be doing many of the jobs currently done by humans."

Answer (score -1, accepted):

'Done' is an *adjective* that indicates either the completion of an event, or ongoing progress toward the completion of an event.

"jobs done by _____" :  the noun in the blank position is acting to do the work of the jobs; he/she/it is the worker. ("jobs done by humans")

"jobs done with ____" : the noun in the blank position describes either a person or thing that facilitates the work ("jobs done with steel"), or that is a characteristic of the completed work ("jobs done with joy").

"jobs done over ____" : the noun in the blank position describes a time period in which the job is completed ("jobs done over Christmas break").

...and other prepositional phrases are possible as well.

Answer (score 1):

You're right that the sentence can be obtained from *which are currently done*, by [Whiz deletion](http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?t=24650)

The shorter form cannot distinguish between *which are currently done* and *which are currently being done*: it might mean either.